# How to check cell value to change value of another?

Tags: vba, excel, amortization

I am working on a loan amortization project.

The loan is amortized over a period of time. Let's say 20 years which has 239 payment lines.

The last row which is generated automatically via an if formula needs some Reconciliations
[image]

As long as the last scheduled payment is less than the actual payment which is 6309 then the scheduled payment should equal 2711 + 4
[image]

I have been trying to edit this code.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton23_Click()

    Dim r1, r2, n As Long
    Dim Pay_Num As Integer, result As String
    Pay_Num = Range("D34").Value
        
    With Sheets("LOANQUIC & Schedule Table") '~~> change to suit
        Dim lrow As Long
        Number_of_Payments = Range("G20").Value
        lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        r1 = Application.Transpose(.Range("A2:A" & lrow))
        r2 = Application.Transpose(.Range("J2:J" & lrow))
        For n = LBound(r1) To UBound(r1)
            If r1(n) <> "" Then r2(n) = r1(n)
            If r1(n) = Number_of_Payments Then Sched_Pay = Number_of_Payments
            Range("D35").Value = Sched_Pay
        Next
        .Range("J2:J" & lrow) = Application.Transpose(r2)
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Working under the assumption, based on your example, that the last row will always contain your last payment, you can just make a quick check on the values and fill in the final payment amount:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Example1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim begBalColumn As Long
    Dim schedPayColumn As Long
    Dim interestColumn As Long
    Dim endBalColumn As Long

    '--- you can automatically set these values if needed
    begBalColumn = 3
    schedPayColumn = 4
    interestColumn = 6
    endBalColumn = 7

    '--- assumes the last row has your last payment
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With ws
        If .Cells(lastRow, begBalColumn).Value < _
               .Cells(lastRow - 1, schedPayColumn).Value Then
            .Cells(lastRow, schedPayColumn).Value = .Cells(lastRow, begBalColumn).Value + _
                                                    .Cells(lastRow, interestColumn).Value
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Otherwise, it's not immediately apparent why you're needing to scan all the rows in your amortization table to find the last row.

Alternatively, you can also use a formula in cell `G5` in your example:

```
=IF(C5<D4,C5+F5,D4)
```